# Does angular class binding impact performance?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been working on a really heavy angular application. I am running through an optimization process and then got a doubt regarding angular **class binding**.

Let's say we have **parent** and **child** elements, Where we do some conditional styling. By `default` the **child** element should be `backgound-color: blue`. But when the **parent** has `expanded` class, The **child** should become `background-color: red`.

**NOTE:** The `expanded` class applies based on a condition.

We can do it in 2 methods.

#### Method 1

**Template**

```
<parent class="parent" [class.expanded]="isExpanded">
     <child class="child"></child>
</parent>
```

**SCSS**

```
.parent {
    .child {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    &.expanded {
        .child {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Method 2

Assume we have some global common classes `bg-blue` and `bg-red`.

**Template**

```
<parent class="parent" [class.expanded]="isExpanded">
     <child class="bg-blue" [class.bg-red]="isExpanded"></child>
</parent>
```

In the above method, we had to add additional **Class Binding** to the child.

#### The Question is,

Which method is efficient in terms of performance to use across the larger angular applications with minimal `DOM` manipulation?

Comment: Don't use dom manipulations in angular. Why not use `*ngIf="isExpanded"` to render the child? I guess you can get best performance by only rendering the stuff you need

Comment: @cloned I mentioned the `display` for just a simple example. But in a real application, there are some other styles too. so `*ngIf` won't be the solution.

Comment: How is this not an opiniated question? If you have a specific usecase, you can always use performance tools of the browser to figure out more. Otherwise I would say: Each component handles it's own state, no need to do so many logic with classes.